# Mexico - What would require Declaration of Legitamate Birth?

Tags: mexico

We find a Legal record of my great grandfather declaring the legitimacy of my grandfather. It includes the statement that he had legitimate civil marriage with his wife, who was deceased. At that time, my grandfather was 6.5 years old.

Coincidentally, this declaration would have been made soon after the time the wife would have died. Does anyone know early 20th century Mexican Family Law and whether her death required this declaration?

Comment: Hi! and welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE. Just a guess, but maybe it was needed for inheritance purposes -- either the wife had property, or a stake in future property (from her parents), Or perhaps start of school needed this in lieu of a birth or baptismal certificate. Which were the states of residence and death (might make a difference)?